# Размытие в canvas

Tags: javascript, html5, веб-программирование, canvas

Рисую простые круги, но нужно их размывать, причем каждый с разной интенсивностью, вот пример кода:

```
    function DrawBubbles(){
        var bubbles = document.getElementById('bubbles'),
            ctx = bubbles.getContext('2d');
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, bubbles.width, bubbles.height);

        function _DrawRound(x, y, radius, blur){
            ctx.fillStyle  = 'rgb(255, 255, 255)'; 
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(x, y, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
            ctx.fill();
        }

        _DrawRound(100, 100, 50, 1);
        _DrawRound(150, 200, 20, 5);
    }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/j44mj752/

Answer (score 3):

Размытие картинки считается попиксельно, путём пересчёта значения яркости в каналах r,g,b с учётом соседей. Варьируется расстояние учитываемых пикселей от текущего, весовые коэффициенты и пр. Вот, например, неплохая [реализация размытия на JS](http://www.quasimondo.com/StackBlurForCanvas/StackBlurDemo.html).

В общем случае перебираются все пиксели изображения. Т.е. вам нужно было бы неэффективно считать размытие каждого из кругов в отдельном «слое» – в отдельных canvas – и потом суммировать яркости с общим слоем.

Отдельный вопрос – наложение одного шара на другой. Яркости складываются? Может, более близкий шар обладает некоторой непрозрачностью, и маскирует собой более удалённые шары? Преломляют ли свет? Вариантов масса, приходим к имитации прозрачных материалов и рей-трейсингу : )

В простом случае - белые круги на черном фоне, можно не расчитывать размытие, а имитировать его, рисуя много кругов близких радиусов с уменьшающейся прозрачностью:

```js
function DrawBubbles() {
  var bubbles = document.getElementById('bubbles'),
    ctx = bubbles.getContext('2d');
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, bubbles.width, bubbles.height);

  function _DrawRound(x, y, radius, blur) {
    var i, alpha, r;
    if (blur) {
      for (i = 0; i < blur; i++) {
        r = radius - (blur / 2) + i;
        if (r <= 0) continue;
        alpha = Math.pow((blur - i) / blur, 4);
        ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(255,255,255,' + alpha + ')';
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(x, y, r, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
        ctx.fill();
      }
    } else {
      ctx.fillStyle = 'rgb(255,255,255)';
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(x, y, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
      ctx.fill();
    }
  }

  _DrawRound(100, 100, 50, 14);
  _DrawRound(150, 200, 20, 10);
  _DrawRound(185, 145, 70, 40);
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) _DrawRound(35 + 45 * i, 290, 16, 8 * i);
}
DrawBubbles();
```

```html
<canvas height="320" width="480" id="bubbles"></canvas>
```

Comment: Я старался избегать грубого расчета  средствами JS, думал, есть встроенное решение. Возможно, это лучше реализовать на WebGL?

Answer (score 1):

> Рисую простые круги, но нужно их размывать

есть функция `createRadialGradient`, пример [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5475755)

Comment: Градиент линеен между двумя стопами. Размытие нелинейно. Если хочется более натурально выглядящее размытие, придётся делать больше стопов в градиенте – имитировать форму плавного колокола набором прямых отрезков.